# Electric density on the edge of a hollow spherical conductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, gauss-law

Suppose I have a sphere with radius $R$ and charge $Q$ and another hollow sphere with inner radius $2R$ and outer radius $3R$ with charge $2Q$, both of them are conductive.

I want to calculate the charge density on the surfaceses of the 2 spheres. for the inner one its easy because the desity is uniform its just $$\sigma = \frac{Q_{in}}{\text{Area}} = \frac{Q}{4\pi R^2}$$

but for the outer sphere i had a problem. i said that the charge of the inner surface is $q$ and then the outer one must be $2Q-q$. and then i tried to use gauss law for a point between $2R$ and $3R$. then
$$\frac{Q_{in}}{\epsilon_0} = \oint _V E \cdot dA$$ 
$$\frac{q+Q}{\epsilon_0} =4\pi r^2 \left( \frac{kQ}{r^2} + \frac{kq}{r^2}\right)$$
$$k(q+Q) = r^2\left( \frac{kQ}{r^2} + \frac{kq}{r^2}\right) = k(q+Q)$$

and then I basically did nothing.
What did I do wrong? How can I find the density of the outer sphere? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spherical conductor with inner and outer radii $2R$ and $3R$ and total charge $2Q$, then all charges stay on the outer suface, so the surface charge density would be $\sigma=\frac{2Q}{4\pi(3R)^2}$. If you have other charges $q$ in addition to $2Q$, then the total charge on the outer surface would be $2Q+q$ and the density is $\sigma=\frac{2Q+q}{4\pi(3R)^2}$. Since the sphere is conductor, NO charge can stay on the inner surface.

Comment: thanks i see, its just doesnt make much sense that there will be no charge on the inner surface

Comment: @EladElmakias The electric filed inside the conductor is always zero (electrostatic condition). Therefore, all charges gather on the outer surface. There is only one exception. If you have some other charges in region $r<2R$, then you CAN have charges on the inner surface. For example, if you have a point charge $q$ at the center, there must be a charge $-q$ on the inner surface, so that $E = 0$ inside the conductor (the Gauss law; $Q_{in}=q+(-q) = 0$).